# Check if Block Device Has Been Used Since Last Factory Reset

Tags: dd, block-device

How do I check if a block device has any useful data on it? Is this even possible to determine programmatically? I care about SD cards specifically, though I'm sure the same or similar rules could apply to any device.

My scenario is that I'm writing Raspberry Pi or some other OS to an SD card, with some initial files possibly, using `dd` as part of a script, and would like to show a prompt if the SD card isn't empty, so the user can recover files if need be. The user would rerun the script with a `-f` option once retrieving all useful files. Since this process is automated, I want the user to do as little work as possible, and answer as few questions as possible. The cards will typically be 8-16GB, but may be more, and that will take a long time to overwrite.

It doesn't matter to me if the card has been formatted since leaving the factory, as long as there is no useful data on it besides things like the boot sector and an initial filesystem. The script shouldn't care what kind of data this is, whether secure, critical, or sentimental/useless data, as long as *someone* wrote to it *sometime* since the last factory reset.

I would like to do this strictly from the command line, preferably bash, without resorting to examining the physical card.

Comment: I don't recommend to write to disk to block device without let the user know, because when you say "there is no useful data on it", it's the user's decision to make, not decision of your script. Data could be stored at the disk anywhere even if without a partition or filesystem. Even for a non-IT guy, data could be stored at disk/partition label: "The disk label is my TODO today, I forgot it, and this script write the the whole partition without let me know."

Comment: I was afraid of something like this. My script is going to be done mostly on factory-fresh SD cards, but not always, and anyway testing is very important.